# Will phone lose pairing if it was paired via WiFi direct and it connected to a WiFi network?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-direct

If a phone and another device is connected via WiFi direct, and the phone detected a home or free public WiFi network, will it connect with the WiFi network and lose pairing with the device it was originally paired to?

Answer (score -1):

It will not connect the other wifi if you didn't connect it manually.

Comment: What if the WiFi network was set as "connect automatically" when detected by the mobile phone? Will connecting to WiFi then break up or cause the WiFi direct pairing to malfunction?

Comment: It will connect only when you end the connection with wifi direct